# NGINX : DELETE method not allowed

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx to serve static pages but to pass requests to an API, which I would like to handle GET, and DELETE requests.

GET work fine, but DELETE request is rejected with "405: Method Not Allowed"

```nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;
    root /var/test/cache/;
    index index.php;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, DELETE';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Origin';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';


    location ~* /questions {
      ...
      
      try_files $url /index.php;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: nginX does not support/allow DELETE method for static files - you must be sure that the request is handled by PHP and does not end on a static file.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks for ur reply, in that case, should I switch to the post method ? weird that Nginx doesn't allow the delete method.

Comment: @algotourist, yes, you should handle `DELETE` method with your backend

Comment: @user973254 still getting the same error message

Comment: Put a `phpinfo();` as the first line of your PHP script and you will see what is the `$_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD']` value. If you can't reach the `phpinfo()` - it means that your HTTP request is not handled by PHP.

Comment: @IVOGELOV When I send a POST request to the server, I'm still getting POST (405)

Comment: @algotourist What is `$request` value in your log file after you've sent a request?

Comment: I don't think you can POST to a static file, too. Try with GET.

Comment: Thanks guys, the issue was resolved by fixing an issue on  fastcgi_params file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

fix an issue on fastcgi_params file, and improve the location rule entry :

```nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;
    root /var/test/cache/;
    index index.php;

    location ~* /questions {
      
      set_by_lua_block $url_format {
        request_type = ngx.var.request_method
        
        if request_type == 'DELETE' then
           ...
           return url_format;
        end
        
        ...
      }
      
      try_files $url_format /index.php;
    }

}
```